# how can I make notification like facebook notification when an invitation is sent with spring boot and angular?

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot

How can I detect database changes and then send notification to admin dashboard with angular spring boot and mysql like facebook notification when an invitation is sent

Comment: Pls do not use mysql as a poor man's notification service! It is jot designed to send notifications. Use a messsge broker / message que solution with built-in notification services, such as fireabase, redis, or rabbit MQ.

Comment: @Shadow is right, even I will suggest you use Firebase for notifications.